# SQL nested if inside of a function with exist and checking timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-functions

I need to check that VIP exist in DB and his time not expired. Everything would be fine if not this problem: how to create Boolean function that will store this functionality?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `IsVip`(steamId VARCHAR(17)) RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN
RETURN EXISTS (SELECT SteamId, Expired FROM Vips WHERE SteamId=steamId AND Expired >= NOW());
END
```

This is my solution, but is this coed efficient well - I mean SELECT statement?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `IsVip`(steamId VARCHAR(17)) RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN
IF (SELECT VipId FROM Vips WHERE SteamId = steamId AND Expired >= NOW())
    THEN
        RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE
        RETURN FALSE;
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Please add the DBMS in your question tag? Some would accept the code above, some wouldn't. Also, what are you trying to do with `steamID=steamID`. Did you incorrectly type the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is only one line per `SteamID` in the `Vips` table, I would just do :

```
SELECT 1 FROM Vips WHERE SteamId = ? AND Expired >= NOW();
```

This will return a single row with a value of `1` when the user is valid (ie exists and is not expired), and an empty recordset if it does not.

Another option :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Vips WHERE SteamId = ? AND Expired >= NOW()
```

Will always return a resultset, with a single record containing either `1` if the user is valid, or `0` if not.